# Ruby on Rails Enum Undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

I've got a user model in rails which includes an attribute `authorization`. I want to design it as an enum which holds the authorization level of the user:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord    
  enum authorization: [default: 0, moderator: 1, admin: 2]
  # User code
end
```

Afterwards I added some methods into my application controller which I want to user in order to verfiy the authorization status of the user in the other controllers.

```
#Application Controller

def moderator_required
  return redirect_to root_path if current_user.nil?
  redirect_to root_path if !current_user.admin? && !current_user.moderator?
end

def admin_required
  return redirect_to root_path if current_user.nil?
  redirect_to root_path unless current_user.admin?
end
```

I found the shortcut `user.admin?` in the [Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

Even though I get the following error when trying to use the admin_required method:

```
undefined method `admin?' for #<User:0x7091e20>
```

Does anyone have an idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using hash. Try changing your enum declaration to:

```
enum authorization: { default: 0, moderator: 1, admin: 2 }
```

Comment: I will go to bed now... Thank you very much, this is the reason why we need more coffee for developers.

Comment: Sure, I just need to wait a few minutes until I can.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from zero and increment by one is the default so you don't even need an hash. This is the same

```
enum authorization: [:default, :moderator, :admin]
```